# Facebook invite friends to application using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) application in the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) using the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) and I need to have a page to invite my friends to the application. Are there any methods in PHP to do the same?

I have seen the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) method for this, but it doesn't match with my requirement (I need it as a page other than the JavaScript popup).

Answer (score 1):

Read [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). If you do not use the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) method, see the *Direct URL Example* paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Marco, but i had already seen this. The problem with me is that the Direct URL Example opens in FB page right.. but i need that as my site page.

Comment: These are the two choices you have – either redirecting to facebook.com, or using the JavaScript version that opens a popup.